# Who exactly is Tricker?

Tags: the-terminator-series, s-m-stirling

In S.M. Stirling's Terminator books, the Tricker character appears throughout the first two as some kind of government representative. He is clearly being set up for something of a grander role- I mean, he goes by "just Tricker"- but it never happens. Doomsday happens and that's all she wrote.

I guess it has always felt like he was a character being developed that we would learn more about, who would play a more integral role, but instead all he did was act as impetus to the story to get things moving along.

Is there any information on just who Tricker is, and maybe if there were originally plans for him to do/be something else that never ended up happening?

Comment: http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Tricker

Comment: That article is about two sentences long and doesn't really address my questions. I'm referring to how Stirling made him this mysterious character who suddenly disappeared without a trace.

Comment: If it was longer and answered your question, I'd have posted it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I'm attempting to clarify why I didn't just go to that wikia article when I was looking this up, my apologies if my response came off unpleasantly, that was not my intention.

Comment: “He is clearly being set up for something of a grander role” — you have have been tricked into thinking this. The Tricker gets the last laugh again!

Comment: I sent [Mr. Stirling](https://smstirling.com/) a query. Hopefully, he answers.